# TexMaker - "File not found" when viewing as pdf

Tags: errors, pdf, texmaker

At the moment I'm having a problem when trying to view my LaTeX file as a PDF. Whether I do it internal or external I both the error "File not found.".

I have no idea what file it means. I've read somewhere it has to with my Acrobat Reader, but I still can't get it fixed. And I think it's worth mentioning that I work on Windows 7, as I've also read that Texmaker on Windows has some bugs.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you compiled the document with e.g. `pdflatex` (Tools --> pdfLateX in Texmaker), so there actually is a PDF file to view?

Comment: Also, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I'm just starting to learn the program, sorry for the foolish question!

Comment: No problem. I added an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The "View PDF" button in TeXmaker only opens an already existing file, that has the same basename as your `.tex` file. Meaning, if you're writing in a file called `MyReport.tex`, it will look for a file called `MyReport.pdf` in the same folder as the `.tex` file, and open this in the specified viewer.

To create a PDF from the source, you have to *compile* the document. The easiest way to do this is usually to use `pdflatex`, which in TeXmaker is called with Tools --> pdfLaTeX (shortcut F6), after which you can view the PDF (shortcut F7). There are also buttons on the toolbar for both

Comment: even after pressing f6 i am not getting any output in the pdf reader...
please need help...

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried opening my tex file in another latex compiling software (Texshop) and it is still not producing a pdf.

Comment: @esmitex Do you mean that you get an error when hitting the *Typeset* button in TeXShop? If so, I don't think you have the same problem, please ask a new question describing what you have tried (preferably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) and which error you get.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I have no idea how. I tried compiling in Latex, pdflatex etc. In the end it created a pdf output when I compiled in Xelatex.

Comment: @esmitex If it worked with `xelatex` but not with `pdflatex`, you have probably loaded a package that can only be used with the former, such as `fontspec` or  `unicode-math`. Depending on package the error message may state this clearly.

Comment: @Nearoo Well, the error is accurate (there is no PDF, so obviously the file cannot be found), though something like "No PDF found, have you compiled the document?" might have been more helpful. You could always direct your complaint directly at the developer though, there is a contact form at the bottom of http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this problem, this is what worked for me.
I was using `\includeonlyframes{current}` to compile a single frame. This allows me to compile only frames with the label **current**. However, none of my frames were labelled as **current**. Consequently, when I do QuickBuild, TexMaker cannot find any frames with the label **current** and thus does not generate any pdf (although it compiles). As a result, I got the file not found error, which essentially means that there is not pdf in the first place because of the way I compiled.