# Problem with quick build

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I just started using texmaker and have now faced a problem with viewing the made file as a pdf-file. I have selected the PdfLaTex + View PDF setting from the Quick Build Command -list. And next to the 'run' button I have selected Quick build -> View PDF. When pressing the 'run' button nothing really happens. There appears to be no errors in my LaTeX, but it won't just show me the PDF. Anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: This can be related to the build command as well as to the showPDF command. Have you already checked if there's a PDF or some auxiliary data files created in the folder where your .tex file is?

Comment: I checked the save folder and there is a auxiliary file but no PDF.

Comment: Is there a logfile too? If yes, does it contain any obvious error messages?

Comment: The files in the save folder are .aux, .synctex, .log and of course  .tex. The program doesn't seem to give any error messages at all. And when checking for errors it pops up a window saying 'No LaTeX errors detected!'.

Comment: So what does the logfile say? When there's a logfile created, something seems to get compiled at least. Unfortunately noone has acrstal ball here to see what's going wrong. So please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) and at least the first 5 and last 10 lines of the logfile to enable us to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Related Question: [TexMaker - “File not found” when viewing as pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45900/texmaker-file-not-found-when-viewing-as-pdf).