# How to write mathematics in cover letter?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I can't write `$\ell_1$` and other mathematics symbol in this cover letter:
what packages are needed?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=full,]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{GaramondNo8}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\nonfrenchspacing

%\setkomavar{fromname}{Ole Nordmann}
%\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Storebakken 15 \\ 5500 Haugesund}
%\setkomavar{fromphone}{+47 5222 8183}
\makeatletter


\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{H.P. \\ K. N.  Technology
Tehran, I. R. Iran
 \\ Email Add.:}
\\ Tel: : }

%\KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
\setkomavar{subject}{COVER LETTER FOR SUBMISSION OF MANUSCRIPT}
%\setkomavar{date}
\opening{Dear Dear Editor,}




\closing{Sincerely}
%\encl{loan application, gift certificate for chocolate}

\begin{itemize}
\item[No.] 1:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{~}|c|@{~}l@{\qquad}|r|}
\hline
    %& Column 1& Column 2\\\hline
Ful name& hatam84analysis@gmail.com  \\\hline
Institution  & ...\\\hline
Country & \\\hline
E-mail Address  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item[No.] 2:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{~}|c|@{~}l@{\qquad}|r|}
\hline
    %& Column 1& Column 2\\\hline
Ful name& ... \\\hline
Institution  & ...\\\hline
Country & \\\hline
E-mail Address  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item[No.] 3:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{~}|c|@{~}l@{\qquad}|r|}
\hline
    %& Column 1& Column 2\\\hline
Ful name& ... \\\hline
Institution  & ...\\\hline
Country & \\\hline
E-mail Address  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item[No.]4:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{~}|c|@{~}l@{\qquad}|r|}
\hline
    %& Column 1& Column 2\\\hline
Ful name& ... \\\hline
Institution  & ...\\\hline
Country & \\\hline
E-mail Address  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A large part of the code you posted is irrelevant to the question. As a result, locating where the problem occurs is difficult. Please distill the code to the bare essentials; in other words, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Besides the brace error in line 25 your code compiles just fine, even if i add an `$\ell$`.

Comment: problem occurs between \opening{Dear Dear Editor,}




\closing{Sincerely}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having an extra }

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why typing math with `$math$` or `\(math\)` should fail to work - but I do see what looks like an error in your code:

```
\begin{letter}{H.P. \\ K. N.  Technology
Tehran, I. R. Iran
 \\ Email Add.:}
\\ Tel: : }
```

has one `}` too much after `\\ Email Add.:`, i.e. this block should read:

```
\begin{letter}{H.P. \\ K. N.  Technology
Tehran, I. R. Iran
\\ Email Add.:
\\ Tel: : }
```

Comment: @ Dear greyshade: yes I want know why typing math with $math$ or  should fail to work between \opening{Dear Dear Editor,} \closing{Sincerely}

Comment: @user60350 did you try removing the surplus `}` as noted in my answer and in the comments on your question? After removing that brace, our example compiles fine for me with `&\ell_1$` inserted between `\opening{Dear Dear Editor,}` and `\closing{Sincerely}`.

Comment: Dear greyshade: yes I remove the brace }  and when I compile I see the massage "File not found"

Comment: @user60350 I can't see any place in your code where you're including any other file, so I can't help you there. But: if you're using TexMaker, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45900/texmaker-file-not-found-when-viewing-as-pdf) for the 'File not found' message given by TexMaker if no .pdf is found for your document.