# File not found with Texmaker

Tags: errors, texmaker, windows

I used to work on Ubuntu, but now I changed to Windows 8.1. I installed both MiKTeX and Texmaker but I keep getting this error when I click on the pdf viewer:

```
File not found
```

Comment: Have you compiled the document before trying to watch it?

Comment: Welcome! I think you may find this [already answered question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45900/37788) useful. Otherwise please provide us with more information like screenshots or anything you might consider helpful.

Comment: Why are we downvoting this question?

Comment: @A.Ellett I'm not the downvoter, but there is indeed very little information included in this post. No directory contents, no file contents, nothing.

Comment: @SeanAllred But then instead of downvoting, we should be making suggestions for how to improve the question (particularly for someone new to the site).

Comment: @A.Ellett Naturally :-)