# macOS 10.12.3 "file not found" in TexMaker when viewing as PDF

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I have the problems of viewing as PDF and it shows `File not Found`.

I looked through all these similar problems, but mine on macOS still can not be solved. It would be very nice of you to help me out.

[TexMaker - "File not found" when viewing as pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45900/texmaker-file-not-found-when-viewing-as-pdf)

[image]

Comment: i did selected PDFLatex~

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of `pdflatex` does not make sense.

Instead of giving the location of texmaker, you should enter the location of `pdflatex`, something like `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex`, so replace the line

```
 "/Applications/texmaker.app" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

with something like

```
"/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

One has to compile it first by Tools > Quick Build (or <kbd>F1</kbd> if it is not used for other system function like mine).